# Trying to enable microphone on Bixby Studio on a Mac

Tags: bixbystudio

I'm using Bixby Studio on a Mac and can't get the mic working - I am running Mojave. I can type input in the simulator and it works great, but can't do any testing using voice input. I checked in the Security & Privacy settings to give access to the mic, but there's no entry for Bixby Studio there. I don't recall it ever asking permission to use the mic - has anyone gotten this to work or know of any workarounds?

UPDATE: I ran Bixby studio on a Windows VM on my Mac and got the Microphone input working that way - seems kind of big kludge though.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Hope someone can point me to a solution.

Comment: This is a known issue for Bixby Studio running on MacOS 10.14 (Mohave) and above and it's being worked on. Please see the related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678301/microphone-input-error-in-bixby-studio-simulator-on-a-mac